# observeNodes and Polymer

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer, observer-pattern

I am trying to figure out the `observeNodes()` API in Polymer.

It's all straightforward (it's all explained in [Observe added and removed children](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#observe-nodes).

I created a really simple element:

```
<dom-module id="element-counter-1">
  <template>
    <p>This is the element counter! The result is: {{childCount}}</p>
    <content id="c"></content>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'element-counter-1',
      attached: function(){
        this.childCount = this.getEffectiveChildren().length;

        this.anObserver = Polymer.dom( this.$.c ).observeNodes( function( info ) {

          // Here, `this` is the element itself
          var addedElements = info.addedNodes.filter(function(node) {
            return (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
          });

          // Here, `this` is the element itself
          var removedElements = info.removedNodes.filter(function(node) {
            return (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
          });


          console.log("Changed!" , info, addedElements, removedElements );
        });
      }
    })
  </script>
</dom-template>
```

Now, if I use it like this:

```
<element-counter-1>
  <p>one</p>
  <p>two</p>
  <p>three</p>
</element-counter>
```

The hook function will be called immediately with `addedElements` being the three `<p>` elements.

The documentation says:

> The first callback from `observeNodes` contains **all** nodes added to the element, *not* the elements added since `observeNodes` was called. This works well if you’re using `observeNodes` exclusively.

However, I assumed this meant "all changes *after* the creation of the elements via the local DOM.

So... when I use `observeNodes` does that mean that I have to *always* expect the observer to be triggered with the *initial* elements the observed one contains?